# Use XMLFeedSpider to parse html and xml

Tags: html, xml, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a webpage were I take the RSS links from. The links are XML and I would like to use the XMLFeedSpider functionality to simplify the parsing.

Is that possible?

This would be the flow:

- GET example.com/rss (return HTML)
- Parse html and get RSS links
- foreach link parse XML

Answer (score 0):

I found a simply way based on the existing [example in the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=XML#xmlfeedspider-example) and looking at the source code. Here is my solution:

```
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from myproject.items import TestItem

class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/feed.xml']
    iterator = 'iternodes'  # This is actually unnecessary, since it's the default value
    itertag = 'item'

    def start_request(self):
        urls = ['http://www.example.com/get-feed-links']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_main)

    def parse_main(self, response):
        for el in response.css("li.feed-links"):
            yield scrapy.Request(el.css("a::attr(href)").extract_first(),
                                 callback=self.parse)

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s', self.itertag,     ''.join(node.extract()))

        item = TestItem()
        item['id'] = node.xpath('@id').extract()
        item['name'] = node.xpath('name').extract()
        item['description'] = node.xpath('description').extract()
        return item
```